# Problema al iterar xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

tengo que coger de un xml que tiene una tabla periódica 2 elementos que tienen el numero 84 y 88 de numero atomico. La cosa es que yo he hecho un for-each de PERIODICTABLE/ATOM/ATOMIC_NUMBER y luego un if para ver si el numero es 84. Una vez allí necesito que me muestre su NAME y su respectivo numero atomico.La etiqueta de este estaría dentro de ATOM pero no sé como asociar el NAME si ya estoy dentro de ATOMIC_NUMBER en el path.He buscado y probado y no sé como hacerlo Gracias.

```
  <PERIODIC_TABLE>
    <ATOM>
     <NAME></NAME>
     <ATOMIC_NUMBER><ATOMIC_NUMBER>
     <OXIDATION_STATES></OXIDATION_STATES>
   </ATOM>
<ATOM>
     <NAME></NAME>
     <ATOMIC_NUMBER><ATOMIC_NUMBER>
     <OXIDATION_STATES></OXIDATION_STATES>
   </ATOM>
</PERIODIC_TABLE>



  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h1>Taula periòdica dels elements</h1>
  <h4>Elements descoberts per Marie Curie</h4>
<xsl:for-each select="PERIODICTABLE/ATOM/ATOMIC_NUMBER">
<xsl:if test="ATOMIC_NUMBER=84">
 <li><xsl select="ATOMIC_NUMBER"></xsl></li>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="ATOMIC_NUMBER=88">
 <li><xsl select="ATOMIC_NUMBER"></xsl></li>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>

  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías quedarte con ATOM y usar algo como

```
<xsl:for-each select="PERIODICTABLE/ATOM/">
  <xsl:if test="ATOMIC_NUMBER=88">
```

para luego quedarte con

```
<li><xsl select="NAME"></xsl></li>
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_if.htm

Comment: Pero si hago eso cuando entro en el if estoy dentro del ATOMIC_NUMBER=88  y dentro de este pongo value-of select=ATOM/NAME ese nombre ya se referirá exactamente a esa etiqueta de ATOM? no sé si me explico.

Comment: He editado para aclarar la idea